# Effect of respiration on Arterial pressure

Tags: physiology, respiration

I am trying to explain the effect of respiration on arterial pressure.
I am looking preferably some visual way to show it.

**How can you show the effect of respiration on arterial pressure?**

I am thinking some kind of figure which has the respiration rate and arterial pressure.

Comment: I did a Google image search for respiration AND "arterial pressure" and found lots of graphs including one at http://69.36.35.38/accp/pccsu/update-evaluation-intravascular-fluid-status-critically-ill-patients?page=0,3 which may be what you are looking for

Comment: @AlanBoyd Your article is about venous pressure (outside of the topic).

Comment: Keep scrolling until you get to Figure 4.

Comment: @AlanBoyd I added two pictures about thing below which I think present the thing. What do you think is the most appropriate one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan's pointing picture is this

[image]

I found this picture better

[image]

but not sure if it is exactly the level respiration to the arterial pressure.